# Getting the value of XML element from array of elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I get the array of xml nodes using jquery with the following code

```
var appointments = new Array();
appointments = $($myXML).find('confirmationNumber');
```

Which returns me:

```
[
  <confirmationNumber>​NX0FH25P​</confirmationNumber>​, 
  <confirmationNumber>​VX0MW251</confirmationNumber>​, 
  <confirmationNumber>​VB0TH252​</confirmationNumber>​,
  <confirmationNumber>​VB0MH253</confirmationNumber>​
]
```

I want to retrieve the value of the following confirmation numbers as texts in array and I dont want to iterate the whole XML

I tried:

```
appointment[i].text() and appointment[i].val();
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to project the text of the elements into a new array without explicitly looping:

```
var confirmationNumbers = $($myXML).find("confirmationNumber").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: but there is one problem. it is not just returning the text. it is actually returning the array of strings of the value. is there any way to get individual strings ?

Comment: @Faizan, yes, you requested an array in your question, so... What do you mean by *individual strings*? Did you try indexing the array (e.g. `confirmationNumber[0]`)?

Comment: I solved the problem by casting it to string. using.toString() like confirmationNumber[0].toString(). actually before it was returning array of strings like ["n","x","0","F","H","2","5","P"], and so on...